# Returning CSV data from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, promise

I have a very simple get method which should get the data from a CSV and format it neatly. But it returns a Promise.

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');

const fs = require('fs')

const path = require("path")

const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../csv-files/Sheet1.csv")

 const getSpreadsheetData = () => {
  fs.readFile(filePath, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
     console.log('promise', neatCsv(data))
     console.log('promise fulfilled', await neatCsv(data))
     neatCsv(data)
  })
}
```

The first console log outputs

```
promise Promise { <pending> }
```

The second console log outputs the data I am trying to get.

```
promise fulfilled [ { Title: '1st Of The Worst',
    startDate: '1970',
    endDate: '1970',
    placeOfPublication: 'Tacoma, WA',
    status: 'LIVE',
    series: 'GI Underground Press',
    UID: 'BBCFJBCI' },
  { Title: '0 to 9',
    startDate: '1967',

    endDate: '1969',
    placeOfPublication: 'New York, NY',
    status: 'LIVE',
    series: 'Literary Magazines',
    UID: 'DFADGDA' } ]
```

My question is how do I correctly handle the promise so I can use the CSV data in my index.js file as so

```
const data = getSpreadsheetData()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a google spreadsheet and return it as a 2d array by any chance? I just finished working on this, thought it might be useful.

Comment: @NickHolden - yes exactly this! Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `require("fs").promises;`

Then you can use async/await like this, and avoid using any `then`:

```
const neatCsv = require("neat-csv");
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "Sheet1.csv");

async function getSpreadsheetData() {
  const data = await fs.readFile(filePath);
  return await neatCsv(data);
}

(async () => {
  const loadedCSV = await getSpreadsheetData();
  console.log(loadedCSV);
})();
```

Comment: Please note you can use `await fs.readFile(filePath);` because I imported `const fs = require("fs").promises;`

Comment: @danivicario rather than console.log loadedCSV how would I return loadedCSV instead?

Comment: @xMayank you can manage the errors like

  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile(filePath);
    return await neatCsv(data);
  } catch (e) {
    // manage error here
  }

Comment: @xMayank you can work both inside an async or in promise fashion if you prefer, as in `getSpreadsheetData().then((loadedCSV) => {
  console.log(loadedCSV);
});

(async () => {
  const loadedCSV = await getSpreadsheetData();
  console.log(loadedCSV);
})();
`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your function to `Promise`. Once `resolve` this will console.
Or `reject` you can add `.catch()` block.

```
 const getSpreadsheetData = () => {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(neatCsv(data))
      })
  })
}

getSpreadsheetData().then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Rather then console.log the res how can I return that instead?

If I wanted to then require this file in another and do something like this below:

`const getSpreadsheetData = require('./get-spreadsheet-data')`

`const something = getSpreadsheetData`

`console.log('hello', something)`

I need `something` to have the values from this getSpreadsheetData script.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a node.js program to retrieve a google spreadsheet, and return it as an array of object, where each object is a sheet(tab) inside the spreadsheet. Each sheet contains some information on that specific sheet, along with a 2d array of the cells, as such:

```
cells=[
    row1[col1,col2,col3],
    row2[col1,col2,col3]
    ]
```

The code exposes getWorksheet(spreadsheet_ID), where spreadsheet_ID is the ID from the URL of the spreadsheet.

It also creates a local copy of the returned array.

---

Here's the code.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const {GoogleSpreadsheet} = require('google-spreadsheet'),
    creds = require('./client_secret.json'), 


/**
 * @Description Authenticate with the Google Spreadsheets API using credentials json. 
 * @param {string} spreadsheet_id  - spreadsheet id to get. Get this from the URL of the spreadsheet
 * Returns the entire raw worksheet.
 * */
async function accessSpreadsheet(spreadsheet_id=SPREADSHEET_ID) {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(spreadsheet_id);
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
    await doc.loadInfo();
    console.log(`${getCurrentTime()}: Loaded raw doc ${doc.title}`);
    return doc;
}
/**
 * @Description This is an async function to retrieve the raw worksheet
 * @param {string} spreadsheet_id  - spreadsheet id to get. Get this from the URL of the spreadsheet
 * */
async function getWorksheet(spreadsheet_id) {
    try {
        let res = await accessSpreadsheet(spreadsheet_id);
        console.log(`${getCurrentTime()}: Organizing sheets for extraction...`);
        res = await getCondensedWorksheets(res.sheetsByIndex);
        createSheetsCopy(res);
        return res;
    } catch (e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}

/**
 * @Description This function returns a promise, once resolved, returns an array of objects. Each object is a condensed version of the worksheet containing the following information: id, title, row count, column count, the header values, and the cells array in a 2d format of cells=[row1[col1,col2,col3],row2[col1,col2,col3]]
 * @param worksheetsArr
 */
async function getCondensedWorksheets(worksheetsArr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(worksheetsArr)) {
        throw `getCondensedWorksheets: worksheets variable passed is not an array. Object passed:\n${worksheetsArr}`;
    }
    let revisedArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetsArr.length; i++) {
    // for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //used for testing, to avoid google's request limit
        console.log(`starting with ${worksheetsArr[i]._rawProperties.sheetId}`);
        revisedArr.push(worksheetsArr[i].getRows().then(function(res){
    

    let thisRevised = {
                id: worksheetsArr[i]._rawProperties.sheetId,
                title: worksheetsArr[i].title,
                rowCount: worksheetsArr[i].rowCount,
                colCount: worksheetsArr[i].columnCount,
                getHeaders: worksheetsArr[i].headerValues,
                cellsArr    :   getCells2dArray(res,worksheetsArr[i].columnCount),
            }
            console.log(`done with ${thisRevised.id}`);
            return thisRevised;
        }))
    }
    return Promise.all(revisedArr).then((res)=>{
        return res;
    })    
}

/**
 * @param {array} thisSheet - a single sheet (tab)
 */
function getCells2dArray(thisSheet, columnCount) {
    let sheetCellsArr = [];
    
    sheetCellsArr = thisSheet.map(row => {
        if (row._rawData.length<columnCount) {
            row._rawData.push(" "); 
        }
        return row._rawData;
    });
    return sheetCellsArr;   
}

const getCurrentTime = function (){
    var date = new Date();
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}:${date.getMilliseconds()}`
}

async function createSheetsCopy(worksheet){
    await fs.writeFile("./remote_sheet_ids.json" , JSON.stringify(worksheet) , 'utf8',()=>{});
    console.log(`${getCurrentTime()}: written file successfully`);
}

module.exports = {
    getCurrentTime,
    getWorksheet
};
```

Comment: what values should the client_secret.json hold?

Comment: That should be your credentials json you receive from google. 
Should look similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVo2w.png)